# Remover aspas do valor num JSONObject no Android

Tags: java, android, json

No meu projeto Android preciso gerar o seguinte resultado Json:

```
{"value":164.40}
```

Porém como remover as aspas do resultado String?

```
JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
json.put("value", "164.40");
```

O retorno está vindo com aspas:

```
{"value":"164.40"}
```

Comment: Já tentou passar sem as apas `json.put("value", 164.40);`?

Comment: Qual pacote você está usando?

Comment: O valor é um retorno String pré-formatado. Estou usando o pacote org.json.JSONObject

Comment: Se fez o que eu falei `json.put("value", 164.40);` ?

Comment: Leia o que eu escrevi, não adianta eu colocar na mão...

Comment: Você colocou na sua pergunta dados fixos se for uma String sendo um texto e é essa a sua duvida tem que passar para número? é essa a sua duvida? se você não for claro nos seus questionamentos fica difícil entender a sua duvida.

Comment: Passei como exemplo, "164.40" é um resultado do tipo String (vindo de outro lugar). Mas já resolvi com o Leonardo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Crie uma classe model para receber os dados, quanto ao Json, recomendo usar a lib do [Gson](https://github.com/google/gson) (google, ela é incrível):

```
Gson mGson = new Gson();
DadosModel mDados = new DadosModel();
mDados = mGson.fromJson(meuJson, DadosModel.class);
```

Sua classe model:

```
public class DadosModel
{
    private double value;

    public double getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public void setValue(double value) {
        this.value = value;
    }
}
```

quando der um put, passe no seguinte formato:

```
json.put("value", 164.40);
```

Comment: Obrigado pela dica Leonardo. Consegui resolver de forma mais simples usando o Gson:
gson.fromJson("164.40", Object.class)